# How to load weights from Pytorch to Keras layer by layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, tf.keras

I have tried tons of methods like `onnx2keras`, `pytorch2keras` and so on. But there would always be something wrong...

Since my model is not really complicated: just a **ResNet18-encoder + Decoder** with some *skip-connections*. I'm considering to simply transfer them one layer by another, from pytorch to Keras.

Before I try I'd like to ask if you have similar experience? I know there's `set_weights` method, but that's for *keras-to-keras* so nothing special. However, Keras is **object-based** model, so how can I assign name-based weights, e.g. `'encoder.bn1.bias', 'encoder.bn1.running_mean', 'encoder.bn1.running_var'` to a BN? I don't want `TF1.x` solutions because all of my work is on TF2.x.

So In my opinion, it would be something like:

```
# 1. Save weights and names from pytorch model
weights_dict = torch_mode.static_dict() 

# 2. Construct Keras model
keras_model = tf.keras.models.Model(...)

# 3. Now load weights for each layer in Keras model
for var_name, weight in weights_dict.items():
    # Assign conv with weight with'encoder.conv1.weight'
    # Assign BN with 'encoder.bn1.weight', 'encoder.bn1.bias', 'encoder.bn1.running_mean', 'encoder.bn1.running_var', 'encoder.bn1.num_batches_tracked'
```

But I don't know how... Look forward to your opinions!

Comment: Strange that ONNX didn't work. Check here: https://learnopencv.com/pytorch-to-tensorflow-model-conversion/ They did almost the same as you wish to do. Maybe it worth to try a bit more with ONNX and fix those parts that went wrong?

Comment: @olegr For simple models like ResNet encoder it's indeed easy. But when I convert the decoder, which takes a tuple of 5 feature map as input, a tuple of 4 depth prediction as output will lead to error. Even I could get the ONNX model with onnxruntime, the conversion to Keras will report error... e.g. a node doesn't exist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass pretrained weights in CNN Pytorch to a CNN in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353171/pass-pretrained-weights-in-cnn-pytorch-to-a-cnn-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try pt2keras and see if it works?

link: https://github.com/JWLee89/pt2keras/

To install pt2keras, type the following in the terminal:

```bash
pip install -U pt2keras
```

Below is a simple example for converting `resnet18`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from torchvision.models.resnet import resnet18

from pt2keras import Pt2Keras

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_shape = (1, 3, 224, 224)

    # Grab model
    model = resnet18(pretrained=False).eval()

    # Create pt2keras object
    converter = Pt2Keras()

    # convert model
    keras_model: tf.keras.Model = converter.convert(model, input_shape, strict=True)

    # Save the model
    keras_model.save('output_model.h5')

    # Do whatever else that you want afterwards ...
```

I have attached the converted keras model visualized using netron:

[image]

> Before I try I'd like to ask if you have similar experience? I know there's set_weights method, but that's for keras-to-keras so nothing special. However, Keras is object-based model, so how can I assign name-based weights, e.g. 'encoder.bn1.bias', 'encoder.bn1.running_mean', 'encoder.bn1.running_var' to a BN? I don't want TF1.x solutions because all of my work is on TF2.x.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, you cannot attach name-based weights to individual parameters in Keras like you can in PyTorch, since keras is layer-based. However, you can name the batch-norm layer, which I am guessing is not very useful to you.